# rapc: c: Error!: Data contribution too large j2me polish

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde, j2mepolish

I am working on a project that uses j2me polish and now i am receiving an error i.e  Using Default Jar Packager

```
creating JAD file [D:\MobileDevelopment\risingkarachi5_21_2012\dist\BlackBerry-5.0-de_DE-risingkarachi.jad].
jdp: Reading template...
jdp: Collecting java classes from D:\MobileDevelopment\risingkarachi5_21_2012\build\real\BlackBerry\5.0\de_DE\source...
jdp: Collecting resources from D:\MobileDevelopment\risingkarachi5_21_2012\build\real\BlackBerry\5.0\de_DE\resources...
jdp: Writing files to project D:\MobileDevelopment\risingkarachi5_21_2012\build\real\BlackBerry\5.0\de_DE\J2ME_Polish_Beispiel.jdp...
jdp: Creating D:\MobileDevelopment\risingkarachi5_21_2012\build\real\BlackBerry\5.0\de_DE\J2ME_Polish_Beispiel.jdp
JDP: Note: project is obfuscated, the generated JDP will not contain the necessary subproject for the imported files.
jdp: Creating D:\MobileDevelopment\risingkarachi5_21_2012\build\real\BlackBerry\5.0\de_DE\J2ME_Polish_BeispielLIB.jdp
rapc: Converting jar to cod for device [BlackBerry/5.0]
rapc: Resolving
rapc: Optimizing
rapc: c: Error!: Data contribution too large: 435372
rapc-call: [java, -Xmx512m, -cp, C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 5.0.0\bin\rapc.jar, net.rim.tools.compiler.Compiler, import=C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 5.0.0\lib\net_rim_api.jar, codename=BlackBerry-5.0-de_DE-risingkarachi, BlackBerry-5.0-de_DE-risingkarachi.rapc, BlackBerry-5.0-de_DE-risingkarachi.jar]
D:\MobileDevelopment\risingkarachi5_21_2012\build.xml:99: rapc failed and returned 97
BUILD FAILED (total time: 13 seconds)
```

I have used all blackberry properties in build.xml and i have followed

http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/platforms/blackberry/ link to to create the blackberry build but still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

my issue has been resolved, this issue occurs when you are using some resources like classes or images are more then 64kb and my single class was 296kb so i was receiving this error and then i divided my that class into multiple small classes.

Thanks